# Perdida de datos al enviar por FormMethod.Post - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo una vista `index` la cual tiene dos `inputs` cuyos valores quiero enviar al controlador, pero el botón que acciona el `Html.BeginForm` se encuentra en una vista parcial por lo cual dichos valores nunca llegan a el controlador, Alguna solución?

Index:

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("UserRegister", "Register", FormMethod.Post))
{
<!--==========================================
 Sección de barra de calculos correspondientes
 ==========================================-->
<div class="contenedorSecundario">
    <!--=============================
      Sección del simulador de credito
      ==============================-->
    <div class="tituloPrestamo" style="border: solid 1px; color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);">
        <h3 class="colorBlanco">¡CALCULA TU PRÉSTAMO!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="contenedorCalendario" id="contenedorCalendario">
        <h4 id="valorMedio">¿Que monto necesitas?</h4>
        <div class="alertaCantidad" id="textoMedValor">
        </div>
        @Html.TextBox(@objCalculoCal.Valor.ToString(), new { @value = @objCalculoCal.Valor.ToString(), @class= "inputText", @onkeypress= "return validaNumericos(event);", @id= "Valor" });
        <span class="underline"></span>
        <div class="rangoActivo">
            <input type="range" id="RangoValorCredito" maxlength="7" step="10000" class="slider" min="@objCalculoCal.ValorMinimo" max="@objCalculoCal.ValorMaximo" value="@objCalculoCal.ValorMinimo"/>
        </div>
        <div class="MaxMin1">
            <p id="ValorMinimo">@objCalculoCal.ValorMinimo</p>
            <p id="ValorMaximo">@objCalculoCal.ValorMaximo</p>
        </div>
        <!---Calendario -->
        <div id="datepicker" class="calendarioPrinipal" style=""></div>
        <!---Fin del Calendario -->
        <div class="rangoActivo1">
            <input type="range" id="RangoPlazoCredito" maxlength="2" step="1" class="slider" min="@objCalculoCal.PlazoMinimo" max="@objCalculoCal.PlazoMaximo" />
        </div>
        <div class="MaxMin1">
            <p id="PlazoMinimo">@objCalculoCal.PlazoMinimo Días</p>
            <p id="PlazoMaximo">@objCalculoCal.PlazoMaximo  Días</p>
        </div>
        <div class="inputsMenu">
            @Html.TextBox(@objCalculoCal.Plazo.ToString(), new { @value = @objCalculoCal.Plazo.ToString(), @class = "inputText", @onkeypress = "return validaNumericos(event);", @id = "Plazo" });
        </div>
        <span class="underline"></span>
    </div>
    <!--=============================
     Fin sección del simulador de credito
     ==============================-->

</div>
<div class="contenedorSecundario2" id="calculosSimulador">
    @Html.Partial("_viewCalculosParciales", objCalculos);
</div>

}
<!--==============================================
 Fin sección de barra de calculos correspondientes
 ==============================================-->
<div class="imagenMedia">
    <img src="~/Content/imagenes/7-06.png" />
</div>
<div class="tituloSolicitar">
    <h1>Requisitos para solicitar mi préstamo</h1>
</div>
<!--==========================================
 Sección imagenes requisitos
============================================-->
<div class="imagenesRequisito">
    <div class="primeraImagen">
        <img src="~/Content/imagenes/List1.png" />
        <p>Estar residiendo en Colombia</p>
    </div>
    <div class="segundaImagen">
        <img src="~/Content/imagenes/List2.png" />
        <p>Ser mayor de 18 años</p>
    </div>
    <div class="terceraImagen">
        <img src="~/Content/imagenes/List3.png" />
        <p>Poseer una cta de ahorros o corriente</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cuartaImagen">
        <img src="~/Content/imagenes/List4.png" />
        <p>Direccion de correo electrónico propio</p>
    </div>
    <div class="quintaImagen">
        <img src="~/Content/imagenes/List5.png" />
        <p>Número celular propio</p>
    </div>
</div>
<!--==========================================
 Fin sección imagenes requisitos
============================================-->
<div class="imagenModos">
    <img src="~/Content/imagenes/fondoModos.png" />
</div>
<div class="separadorGrande">
    <img src="~/Content/imagenes/separadorGrande.png" />
</div>
<div class="comoFuncionamos">
    <h2>Así es como funcionamos</h2>
</div>
<div class="leerMas">
    <button class="botonLeer">
        Leer más
    </button>
</div>
<!--==========================================
 Sección Imagenes Aliados
 ==========================================-->
<div class="nuestrosAliados">
    <h2>Nuestros aliados</h2>
</div>
<!--==========================================
 Fin sección Imagenes Aliados
==========================================-->
<div class="nuestrosAliadosImagenes">
    <div class="slider1">
        <div class="slide-track">
            <div class="slide1">
                <img src="~/Content/imagenes/primerAliado.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="slide1">
                <img src="~/Content/imagenes/segundoAliado.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="slide1">
                <img src="~/Content/imagenes/tercerAliado.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="slide1">
                <img src="~/Content/imagenes/cuartoAliado.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="slide1">
                <img src="~/Content/imagenes/quintoAliado.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="slide1">
                <img src="~/Content/imagenes/sextoAliado.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="slide1">
                <img src="~/Content/imagenes/septimoAliado.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="slide1">
                <img src="~/Content/imagenes/octavoAliado.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="slide1">
                <img src="~/Content/imagenes/novenoAliado.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="slide1">
                <img src="~/Content/imagenes/decimoAliado.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="slide1">
                <img src="~/Content/imagenes/onecavoAliado.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer id="footer" class="footer-1">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="float-left">
            @Html.Partial("_Footer")
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Vista parcial `_viewCalculosParciales`:

```html
    <div class="contenedorBarra">
        <div class="barraIntereses">
            <div class="titulosIntereses">
                <div class="contenidoIntereses separador">
                    <p class="colorNegro" id="valorCredito1">Valor Solicitado</p>
                    <p class="colorRojo" id="MostrarValorCredito">@objCalculos.ValorSolicitado</p>
                </div>
                <div class="contenidoIntereses separador">
                    <p class="colorNegro" id="valorInteres1">Interés</p>
                    <p class="colorRojo" id="valorInteres">@objCalculos.ValorInteres</p>
                </div>
                <div class="contenidoIntereses separador">
                    <p class="colorNegro" id="valorSeguro1">Seguro</p>
                    <p class="colorRojo" id="valorSeguro">@objCalculos.ValorSeguro</p>
                </div>
                <div class="contenidoIntereses separador">
                    <p class="colorNegro" id="valorEstudio1">Estudio</p>
                    <p class="colorRojo" id="valorEstudio">@objCalculos.ValorEstudio</p>
                </div>
                <div class="contenidoIntereses separador">
                    <p class="colorNegro" id="valorPlataforma1">Plataforma</p>
                    <p class="colorRojo" id="valorPlataforma">@objCalculos.ValorPlataforma</p>
                </div>

                <div class="contenidoIntereses">
                    <p class="colorNegro" id="valorIva1">Iva</p>
                    <p class="colorRojo" id="valorIva">@objCalculos.ValorIva</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--==========================================
    Sección gran total
    ==========================================-->
    <div class="granTotal">
        <div class="tituloTotal">
            <p>Total a pagar:</p>
            <p id="valorTotal" class="valorTotal">@objCalculos.ValorTotal</p>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="botonPrinipal">
            <button class="botonGrande" type="submit" id="solicitarPrestamo">!Solicitar Prestamo¡</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--==========================================
    Fin sección gran total
    ==========================================-->
```

El botón solicitar préstamo es quien ejecuta el `Html.BeginForm` y debería enviar los datos de los Editor `Valor` y `Plazo` en la vista del `index`.

Controlador:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UserRegister(int? Valor, int? Plazo)
    {         
        tbl_personaModel modelo = new tbl_personaModel();
        if (Valor == null && Plazo == null)
        {
            Valor = 0;
            Plazo = 0;
        }
        modelo.lstCatalogoTipoDocumento = this._creditoregistroBL.MuestraCatalogo("IdTipoDocumento","cat_tipodocumento").MapperToSelectListItems(o => o.Nombre, n => n.IdRegistro, null, null);
        return View(modelo);
    }
```

El controlador `UserRegister` recibe los datos de `Plazo` y `Valor`.

**Actualización** `objCalculos` y `objCalculoCal` Son elementos los cuales llamó para obtener respuestas a modelos diferentes a métodos del controlador.

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Inicio";
    CalculosSolicitud objCalculos = new CalculosSolicitud();
    CalculosCalendario objCalculoCal = new CalculosCalendario();

    if (Model.calculosSolicitud != null)
    {
        objCalculos = Model.calculosSolicitud;
    }
    if (Model.calculosCalendario != null)
    {
        objCalculoCal = Model.calculosCalendario;
    }

}
```

Comment: Has probado con @{Html.RenderPartial("_viewCalculosParciales", objCalculos); }

Comment: Si, pero manda los valores en 0

Comment: Si, ahora ya llega a el controlador, pero en 0 y pues no es la idea. :/

Comment: Que es `objCalculoCal` y `objCalculos` puedes indicarlo también en la pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que veo no tienes ninguna etiqueta name, los formularios se bindean por la etiqueta name al controlador, ponle name a los parametros que quieras "submitir" de manera que coincidan con las variables y debería funcionar 
Ej:

```
    <div class="inputsMenu">
        @Html.TextBox(@objCalculoCal.Plazo.ToString(), new { @value = @objCalculoCal.Plazo.ToString(), @class = "inputText", @onkeypress = "return validaNumericos(event);", @id = "Plazo", @name ="Plazo"});
    </div>
```

Comment: Osea el primer atributo sería "Valor" y no el objeto que pongo.?

Comment: a que te refieres con el primer atributo?, el campo que quieras que vaya al controlador tendra que tener en su html la etiqueta con el "name = Valor" para que "suba" al controlador